# combining multiple mySQL queries with join

Tags: mysql, join

I would like to combine several mySQL queries into one result table.
An example:

```
+---------+--------------+--------------+
| Date    | Order number | Order status |
+---------|--------------|--------------|
| 1/1/13  | 1            | Open         |
| 1/3/13  | 1            | Confirmed    | 
| 2/1/13  | 2            | Open         |
| 2/10/13 | 2            | Confirmed    |
| 2/20/13 | 1            | Shipped      |
| 3/13/13 | 2            | Shipped      |
...
```

I would like to have a query give me this result table:

```
+-------+--------------+----------------+
| Month | Total orders | Shipped orders |
+-------|--------------|----------------|
| 1/13  | 1            | 0              |
| 2/13  | 2            | 1              |
| 3/13  | 1            | 1              |
+-------+--------------+----------------+
```

Total orders reflects the orders with any activity on them, and the shipped orders is self explanatory.

I can get a result table with the "Month" & "Total orders" column with this:

> select date_format('Date', '%c %y') as Month, count(distinct 'Order number') as Total orders from table group by Month

and a result table with the "Month" & "Shipped" orders column with this:

> select date_format('Date', '%c %y') as Month, count(distinct 'Order number') as Shipped orders from table where 'Order Status' = 'Shipped' group by Month

How can I combine these 2 select queries to give me the one table above?  I think I need to do some sort of join using the "Month", but can't figure it out.

Comment: You can use a pivot table. This is a good tutorial: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=523

Comment: One point of clarification.  Your desired results indicate that there are 2 total orders in 2/13.  The data shows only one NEW order (status = Open) in this month.  Is it your desire for Total Orders column to capture all NEW orders in a month or all order that had some activity on them in the month (i.e. open, confirmed, or shipped)?

Comment: To clarify --I'd like the Total Orders column to capture all orders that had some activity on them in the month (i.e. open, confirmed, or shipped).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d25856/44)demo

```
SELECT 
B.MONTH_YEAR, B.ORDER_CNTS, C.SHIPPED_ORDERS
FROM
(
SELECT MONTH_YEAR , COUNT(ORDERNO) AS ORDER_CNTS
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(CAST(MONTH(B.O_DATE) AS CHAR), '/', CAST(YEAR(B.O_DATE)  AS CHAR)) AS MONTH_YEAR , (ORDERNO) AS ORDERNO 
FROM SAMPLE AS B
)
 B
GROUP BY MONTH_YEAR
) AS B
,
(
SELECT MONTH_YEAR , SUM(SHIPPED_ORDERS )AS SHIPPED_ORDERS
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(CAST(MONTH(B.O_DATE) AS CHAR), '/', CAST(YEAR(B.O_DATE)  AS CHAR)) AS MONTH_YEAR ,
  (CASE WHEN ORDER_STATUS= "Shipped" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SHIPPED_ORDERS
FROM SAMPLE AS B
)
 B
GROUP BY MONTH_YEAR
) AS C
WHERE B.MONTH_YEAR = C.MONTH_YEAR
```